# 80s-90s (?) cartoon about a werewolf - something like Scooby Doo knock off

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, werewolf

I remember an old cartoon, but I cannot find it. I saw it in the 90s on Cartoon Network, but the animation was older.

It was like *Scooby Doo*, but male protagonist was something like werewolf - if he's shown a picture of the moon, he turns into a wolf and when "they" show him a picture of the Sun, he turns back into human. It wasn't the *Scooby Doo* movie - that I know for sure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## *Fangface* (1978 - 1980)

> [image: *Fangface* title card]
>
> Highly derivative of *Scooby-Doo* (which was also created by Ruby and Spears) with a bit of the Tasmanian Devil and *I Was A Teenage Werewolf* thrown in, Fangface features four teenagers — buff and handsome leader Biff, his brainy and beautiful dusky-skinned girlfriend Kim, short, stocky and pugnacious Puggsy and tall, skinny simpleton Sherman "Fangs" Fangsworth..., the latter of whom transforms into a wildly whirling werewolf named Fangface whenever he looks at the full moon, a picture of the moon, or anything resembling the moon.
>
> — Wikipedia: [*Fangface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fangface)

Comment: Yes! You are a true hero :D